# How to log mysql queries of specific database - Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, server, hosting

I have been looking at this post
[How can I log "show processlist" when there are more than n queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778913/how-can-i-log-show-processlist-when-there-are-more-than-n-queries)

It is working fine by running this command

```
mysql -uroot -e "show full processlist" | tee plist-$date.log | wc -l
```

the problem it is overriding the file

I also want to run it in cronjob.

I have added this command to the `/var/spool/cron/root`:

```
* * * * * [ $(mysql -uroot -e "show full processlist" | tee plist-`date +%F-%H-%M`.log | wc -l) -lt 51 ] && rm plist-`date +%F-%H-%M`.log
```

but it is not working. Or maybe it is saving the log file some place out of the root folder.

So my question is: how to temporarily log all queries from specific database and specific table and save the whole queries in 1 file?

Note: it is not slow/long queries log I am looking for, but just temp solution to read which queries are running for a database

Comment: If you want `tee` to append to the file instead of replacing it, use the `-a` option.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` character has special meaning in `crontab` commands, you need to escape them. So you need to do:

```
* * * * * [ $(mysql -uroot -e "show full processlist" | tee plist-`date +\%F-\%H-\%M`.log | wc -l) -lt 51 ] && rm plist-`date +\%F-\%H-\%M`.log
```

If you want to use your original command, but not overwrite the file each time, you can use the `-a` option of `tee` to append:

```
mysql -uroot -e "show full processlist" | tee -a plist-$date.log | wc -l
```

To run the command every second for a minute, write a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..60}; do
    [ $(mysql -uroot -e "show full processlist" | tee -a plist.log | wc -l) -lt 51 ] && rm plist.log
    sleep 1
done
```

You can then run this script from cron every minute:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
```

Although if you want to run something continuously like this, `cron` may not be the best way. You could use `/etc/inittab` to run the script when the system boots, and it will automatically restart it if it dies for some reason. Then you would just use an infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
    [ $(mysql -uroot -e "show full processlist" | tee -a plist.log | wc -l) -lt 51 ] && rm plist.log
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: this command is fine for me

* * * * * [ $(mysql -uroot -e "show full processlist" | tee -a plist.log | wc -l) -lt 51 ] && rm plist.log

but i have added it in /var/spool/cron/root

but where can i find the log file?

Comment: It should be in root's home directory, probably `/root`.

Comment: Use `cd ~root` to go to root's home directory.

Comment: yes you are right,  i forgot that this * * * *   run every minute,   i want it to run every second    iam not sure if it is possible to */60 * * * *   ?

Comment: No, cron can't run more than once a minute. You can run a shell script that uses a loop that runs once a second.

Comment: could you please guide me how to do this shell script?

Comment: hmm okay.

when running this  ##watch -n 1  "mysqladmin -u root -pXXXXX processlist | grep tablename"  | tee -a /root/plist.log

iam getting these characters   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17796755/111.png

in notepad or word it is not having these characters.

also i would ask how to well format the queries to show on new line  instead of in one line.   the timestamps are not important.  only queries

Comment: `watch` is a full-screen program, those are the escape sequences used to move the cursor around on the screen.

Comment: could you please try to look at this question instead
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756962/how-to-print-mysql-process-list-instead-of-using-watch-ssh-command

Comment: Doesn't the `while` loop in my answer show how to do that? Aren't you capable of generalizing these things, or do you really need everything done for you?

Answer (score 0):

solution is:

```
watch -n 1  "mysqladmin -u root -pXXXXX processlist | grep tablename"  | tee -a /root/plist.log
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.